# Unity new GameObject created by script are not in respective scene

Tags: c#, singleton, unity-game-engine

I modify a singleton so that it works for a `scene` only, I also remove the DontDestroyOnLoad() and reset the _instance into null.

But the problem is, this new singleton GameObject is placed on other scene. So when the scene unload, It will not destroy since it is on other scene.

The `SingletonScene` should be in its respective scene which is `Kanga1`.

[image]

```
public class SingletonScene<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static T _instance;

    private static object _lock = new object();

    public static T instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = (T)FindObjectOfType(typeof(T));

                    if (FindObjectsOfType(typeof(T)).Length > 1)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("[Singleton] Something went really wrong " +
                            " - there should never be more than 1 singleton!" +
                            " Reopening the scene might fix it.");
                        return _instance;
                    }

                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        GameObject singleton = new GameObject();
                        _instance = singleton.AddComponent<T>();
                        singleton.name = "(SingletonScene) " + typeof(T).ToString();

                        Debug.Log("[SingletonScene] An instance of " + typeof(T) +
                            " is needed in the scene, so '" + singleton +
                            "' was created");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.Log("[Error] this should not happen on SingletonScene " +
                            _instance.gameObject.name);
                    }
                }

                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        _instance = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just recently read about the possibility to set active scenes using [SceneManager.SetActiveScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.SetActiveScene.html). The reference says: "The active scene is the scene which will be used as the target for new GameObjects instantiated by scripts.", I haven't used it yet, though.

Comment: Brill @Lelefant, It works

Comment: Are you using DontDestroyOnLoad() ?